# Can't get user input to display using forms and controllers in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, controller

I'm new to coding, and so I'm sure there's a concept that I'm missing that will help me figure this out, but I can't figure out what that is. I have an application where a user (on the home page) enters a phone number and an sms message. After they hit send, it takes them to a page where they can view the data that they inputted. I can't get my application to display the data! In the next step, I will be sending the data to twilio, so I can't change where my home page routes to.

Here is my code:

home.html.erb

```
<div class="jumbotron center">
    <h1>Quick Chat <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" aria-
hidden="true"></span></h1>
    Submit an SMS message here!

<%= render :file => "home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/messages/new.html.erb" 
%>
```

new.html.erb

```
 <%= render 'messages/form' %>

  <p>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Phone Number</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= form_tag(sms_send_path, method: "post") do %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:number, nil, placeholder: 'Enter number 
            here...', size: 75) %>
          <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </p>

    <p>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">SMS Message</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= form_tag(sms_send_path, method: "post") do %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:text, nil, placeholder: 'Enter text 
            here...', size: 75) %>
          <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </p>


<%= form_tag(sms_send_path, method: "post") do %>
  <%= submit_tag("Send", :class => "btn btn-success btn-lg") %>
<% end %>
```

sms.html.erb

```
<div class="jumbotron center">
    <h1>Quick Chat <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" aria-    hidden="true">    </span></h1>

   <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-    label="Close">    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Success!</strong> Your SMS message has been sent! <span         class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   </div>

<%= render :file => "home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/messages/show.html.erb"         %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= render 'messages/form' %>

<p>
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Phone Number</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <%= @message.number %>
    </div>
  </div>
</p>

<p>
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">SMS Message</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <%= @message.text %>
    </div>
  </div>
</p>
```

form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :message do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_message, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @messages = Message.all
  end

  def show
    @messages = Message.find(message_params)
  end

  def new
    set_message
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    set_message
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if @message.save
      redirect_to sms_send_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def update
      if @message.update(message_params)
        redirect_to @message
      else
        render :edit
      end
  end

  def destroy
    @message.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      redirect_to messages_url
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_message
      @message = Message.find(message_params)
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white     list through.
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:number, :text)
    end

end
```

I'm worried I've created one big mess by not grasping a core concept. I have been unable to find the answer by google, but it's possible that's because I've been searching for the wrong question. Thanks for taking the time to help me!

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but the data(@message.number and @message.text) will not display.

Comment: try debugging `set_message` and `message_params`, what do you get in them?

Comment: Cannot render console from 70.214.82.43! Allowed networks: 
    127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
      ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.7ms)  SELECT 
    "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  
    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/tasks"):

Comment: I think that's a byebug error though?

Comment: just try printing them in logs using `puts` or `p`.

Comment: Started GET "/" for 70.214.82.43 at 2017-05-03 14:54:19 +0000
Cannot render console from 70.214.82.43! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendering messages/new.html.erb
  Rendered messages/_form.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered messages/new.html.erb (7.8ms)
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (13.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 246ms (Views: 243.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: this is the only error I can see

Answer (score 0):

To start this is how the following files should look:

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'messages/form' %>
```

**Update**

Changes made to *form.html.erb* file below:

1. the first line `form_for`
2. the first `text_field_tag`
3. the second `text_field_tag`
4. changed `submit_tag` to `f.submit`

**form.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for @message do |f| %>

    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Phone Number</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <%= f.text_field(:number, placeholder: 'Enter number here...', size: 75) %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">SMS Message</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <%= f.text_field(:text, placeholder: 'Enter text here...', size: 75) %>
      </div>
    </div>

  <%= f.submit("Send", :class => "btn btn-success btn-lg") %>
<% end %>
```

Secondly, I know it's a long read, but please go through [Rails Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) to have a better understanding of how this should all fit together.

**Update**

Remove `set_message` from `new` and `create` method. Change `set_message` method as follows:

```
def set_message
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
end
```

Usually, based on the routes file, you will find a record based on its `id`. In your terminal run `rake routes` and you will see that there should be a routes that corresponds to:

```
messages POST /messages(.:format) messages#create
new_message GET /messages/new(.:format) messages#new
edit_message GET /messages/:id/edit(.:format) messages#edit

message GET /messages/:id(.:format) messages#show
  PATCH /messages/:id(.:format) messages#update
  PUT /messages/:id(.:format) messages#update
  DELETE /messages/:id(.:format) messages#destroy
```

which means that it will use the `params[:id]` value to in the URL and you can use that to find the corresponding `Message` that has been saved in the database. Also take a look at [Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for a better understanding of this.

Comment: Thanks so much! I adjusted my program as suggested, but your code is raising a syntax error

Comment: what is the syntax error? and for which controller action?

Comment: I had to adjust the code you had written, but I see you updated it as well. I believe I am getting closer to the problem. My new error is in the set_message as previously thought by Md. Farhan Memon above.

Comment: I updated my answer to include more info about Rails routing